# How do I populate a DataTable by calling a servlet in

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, datatables

I am new to java servlets and dataTables  I am having difficulty getting my java servlet to execute:

I am using netbeans 8.2 IDE with tomcat 8.0.27 and DataTables 10.1.16

my NetBeans structure looks like the following:
[image: Netbeans Structure]

and the War looks like this:
[image: WAR Structure]
my index.jsp looks like this:

DataTable definition (in the html head section)

```js
 <script lang='javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#memberList').dataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SubSearch",
                    "type": "GET" 
                }

              });
              
           });
        </script>

Html Body:
```

```html
 <body>
        <h1>Member TXN Display</h1>
        <div>
            (Enter Search Criteria)<br/>
            <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SubSearch" method="post"  >
               
                <input type="text" id="SearchCritiera" style="width:322px">
                <input type="submit" value="FIND">
                <table id="memberList">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Member #</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

context.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/MemberTXN"/>
```

Clicking the Submit (Find) button invokes the servlet, however, 'ajax' doesn't seem to hit at all.  I have breakpoints in the servlet that I would expect to be hit when I run in 'Debug' mode as a result of the document.ready code, but no dice.

Servlet Code:

```
 package member;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.google.gson.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ainsworth
 */
 @WebServlet(name = "SubSearch", urlPatterns = {"/SubSearch"})
public class SubSearch extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


        JsonObject jMembers = new JsonObject();
        jMembers.addProperty("Echo","1");
        jMembers.addProperty("TotalRecords", 7);
        jMembers.addProperty("TotalDisplayRecords", 7);



        JsonArray data = new JsonArray();

        JsonArray row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456789");
        row.add("Trump");
        row.add("Donald");
        data.add(row);

        row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456799");
        row.add("Clinton");
        row.add("Hillary");
        data.add(row);

         row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456809");
        row.add("Shcumer");
        row.add("Chuck");
        data.add(row);

         row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456819");
        row.add("Warren");
        row.add("Elizabeth");
        data.add(row);

         row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456829");
        row.add("Sanders");
        row.add("Bernie");
        data.add(row);

         row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456839");
        row.add("DeVoss");
        row.add("Betsy");
        data.add(row);


        row = new JsonArray();
        row.add("123456849");
        row.add("Meyers");
        row.add("Seth");
        data.add(row);

        jMembers.add("Data", data);

        response.setContentType("application/Json");
        response.getWriter().print(jMembers.toString());




}


/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
 }

 }
```

And here is the output of the submit button:

[image: Submit Results]
If someone could point out the error of my ways, I would be very appreciative

Comment: I have added the Servlet code to the description.  Note:  Originally I had not bothered code valid Json.  This is, of course mocked up data, but as you can see the output is as expected when the servlet is invoked with the submit key.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

You can use `ajax.dataFilter` option to alter the JSON structure, because the API expects the structure like this by default:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [{...},{...}]
}
```

Using dataFilter to alter JSON structure :

```
$('#memberList').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SubSearch",
        "type": "GET",
        dataFilter: function(data){
         var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
         json.recordsTotal = json.TotalRecords;
         json.recordsFiltered = json.TotalDisplayRecords;
         json.data = json.Data;

         return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
        }
    }
```

**OPTION 2:**

If you have a chance to change server API data structure, then build the JSON with appropriate keys like below.

```
jMembers.addProperty("echo","1"); //important case-sensitive
jMembers.addProperty("recordsTotal", 7);
jMembers.addProperty("recordsFiltered", 7);
jMembers.add("data", data);
```

---

**ALSO SEE:**

- [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: Thanks, Gurkan.  Your comments may indeed prove useful.  However, I am not getting far enough at this point to have notice the issue you have addressed.  My issue is the code in $(document)ready(function() ...) is not being executed, as  my breakpoint does not get hit.  The breakpoint does get hit when the form is submitted.

Comment: If you type localhost:8080/MemberTXN/index.jsp and datatable not filling with your server data then you need to check client libs. first jquery lib and after datable.js need to include the page.

Answer (score 0):

To Quote Firefox:  Well, this is embarrassing:

I finally determined that my Javascript was not being executed.  The problem was that my `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` was missing the `>` before the `</script>`

Thanks again to Gurkan now that I am executing my server code, your post will help me determine why I am not filling my table.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you have fixed your problem. I actually tried to explain it my last comment.I would be happy if you mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your algorithm inside of doGet or doPost